# sharepoint Calendar year view

Tags: sharepoint-calendar

[image]

I have created a calendar in which i can see event based on "days, week & month". I have to create a year view in which i can see each months in view under particular year. Is there any approach using jQuery?

Comment: is this solution helps you in achieving your desired result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> SharePoint 2013 Calendar doesn't provide a year/quarter view by
>   design, as a workaround you can create a "Gantt view" for your
>   Calendar list, this view has Zoom In/Zoom Out options to make the
>   items be displayed in quarter/year view, you can take a look.
>
> [image]